# is it possible to hyperlink to external pdf selection?

Tags: pdf, content-management-system, hyperlink, selection, anchor

I'd like to create hyperlink references to a text selection or offset in an external PDF document, as if there were an anchor defined. E.g.,  `http://lib.extern.org/doc1.pdf?page=3&paragraph=4`   so that when the user follows the link in their browser, the PDF document opens positioned at the offset specified. I'm looking for any granularity, e.g. page, paragraph, line, word, character or even pixel em or inch offset would be acceptable. If a range for a selection could be specified that would be ideal, the purpose being to highlight and link directly to quotes in external PDF docs (to which the app has read-only access.)  Seems so basic, but I haven't found a solution.  Ideas?

Comment: This functionality is dependent on the PDF viewer being used, which isn't always Adobe Reader.  Just keep that in mind when using this.

Answer (score 2):

It appears it [works for page numbers](http://www.slaw.ca/2006/06/21/web-tip-deep-linking-into-pdf-documents/)

EDIT: And also [check this](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDFOpenParameters.pdf#page=8) (it should open on page 8)

Comment: Given Brad's comment, is there any mechanism that could work across major viewers, e.g. including Preview on MacOS, built-in browser viewers for Chrome, etc.?    Short of rendering on the server and serving the rendered image--I'd like to deliver the original PDF from the original link but then do the positioning/highlighting on the client.

Answer (score 1):

There are no standards for commandline parameters for the plugins.

But if you can render a fresh PDF each time (make a copy and put in a new object via some PDF manipulation API), you can include an OpenAction that jumps to the page in question. You can even set more viewer parameters (or do some other personalization, watermarks, whatever...).

Comment: That's a helpful direction too. Was hoping to not mess with parsing and augmenting the PDF itself but it might be the ultimate solution. Any sense of how non-Adobe viewers would support this?

Comment: Our one is doing so :-)    Joking apart - nearly any serious viewer should honor this. I do not know how Mac behaves...  PDF manipulation at this stage should be very easy and available at no cost in any programming language.